# VB Timer Countdown

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have an action take place, then wait 3 seconds, then proceed with the rest of the code.

I have a timer in the designer named tmrTurnTimer set to an interval of 3000. The tick event is as follows

```
Private Sub tmrTurnTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTurnTimer.Tick

    Dim intTimer As Integer = 3

    If intTimer > 0 Then
        lblEnemyDamage.Text = intHeroAtk.ToString()
        intTimer -= 1
    Else
        tmrTurnTimer.Stop()
        lblEnemyDamage.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I call the tick event after the hero has attacked with hopes of a three second delay before the enemy attacks back, however, it is all done at once as damage is shown in both hero and enemy labels at the same time as soon as "Attack" is clicked.

```
'Call Attack Sub with Hero damage ranges plugged in
            Attack(intHeroAtk, 5, 31, intEnemyHP, 8, 14)

            'Display damage done in Enemy damage label
            lblEnemyDamage.Text = intHeroAtk.ToString()


            'If the enemy health is above zero
            If intEnemyHP > 0 Then

                'Start timer and display damage from hero in enemy damage label
                tmrTurnTimer.Start()

                'This is where I would like the program to wait for 
                'three seconds before proceeding

                'Call Attack Sub with Enemy damage ranges plugged in
                Attack(intEnemyAtk, 5, 21, intHeroHP, 10, 11)

                'Display damage done in Hero damage label
                lblHeroDamage.Text = intEnemyAtk.ToString()

                DisplayStats(intHeroHP, intHeroMP)
```

Forgive me if this is a stupid request.

Comment: You need to declare `Dim intTimer As Integer = 3` outside of the `tmrTurnTimer_Tick` method otherwise everytime the timer ticks it will be initialised with the value of 3 and will never get down to 0. (This is just a small observation and might not actually fix the issue you are having).

Comment: Good observation. I will attempt and report back.

Comment: @Jinx88909 Put `Public intTimer As Integer = 3` in a module. No luck. It still all processes at the same time.

Comment: Yeah OK the timer is started and the processing of the method continues (I've just read your comments, sorry). You might be able to use [Thread.Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx) to delay. I haven't tested this so unsure of how it will react but give it a go.

Comment: @Jinx88909 I tried putting `Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)` both underneath `If intEnemyHP > 0 Then` and in the tick event itself. Nothing. I just feel like the timer isn't even starting because even after three seconds.. `tmrTurnTimer.Stop()
        lblEnemyDamage.Text = ""` The enemy damage label doesn't even clear. Maybe I need to take a break and come back to it.

Comment: Just check you've enabled the timer and set it up correctly. Place a breakpoint inside the timer code and see if the breakpoint actually hits.

Comment: Almost a year now...  I think he "took a break" and never "came back to it".

Answer (score 0):

First off Timers do not work like you think. They do not pause the UI Thread, They do the opposite, they fire off on their own thread and let the UI get on with its business. The Timer will notify the UI thread when it's time has elapsed. What you need to do is put your code that needs to happen after the 3 seconds has passed in the tmrTurnTimer_Tick event method. If you want the damage text to disappear after 1 second then I would put that on a different Timer set to 1 seconds.

```
'Call Attack Sub with Hero damage ranges plugged in
        Attack(intHeroAtk, 5, 31, intEnemyHP, 8, 14)

        'Display damage done in Enemy damage label
        lblEnemyDamage.Text = intHeroAtk.ToString()


        'If the enemy health is above zero
        If intEnemyHP > 0 Then

            'Start timer and display damage from hero in enemy damage label
            tmrTurnTimer.Start()
    lblEnemyDamage.Text = intHeroAtk.ToString()
    tmrEnemyDamageTimer.Start()
```

Turn Code

```
    Private Sub tmrTurnTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTurnTimer.Tick

    tmrTurnTimer.Stop()

                'Call Attack Sub with Enemy damage ranges plugged in
                Attack(intEnemyAtk, 5, 21, intHeroHP, 10, 11)

                'Display damage done in Hero damage label
                lblHeroDamage.Text = intEnemyAtk.ToString()

                DisplayStats(intHeroHP, intHeroMP)
End Sub
```

Enemy Damage Code (need to create another timer)

```
    private Sub tmrEnemyDamageTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTurnTimer.Tick

    tmrEnemyDamageTimer.Stop()
    lblEnemyDamage.Text = ""
End Sub
```